# auto suggest cant preview , but get the result

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I am doing a login/logout page. I face a problem with auto suggest. 
If without the code below, the auto suggest is working with list. 
But if i add on the code below, the auto suggest not working mean i can't get the suggestion list. I have do some test, although can't get the list, the result will still appear.

Sorry, this is file for application.cfm , my autosuggest is another file.

```
 <cfif GetAuthUser() NEQ "">

  <cfquery name="loginQuery" dataSource="Reservation">
   SELECT *
    FROM User_Customer
    WHERE Email = '#GetAuthUser()#'

    </cfquery>

<cfoutput query="loginQuery">

   <form action="#CGI.script_name#?#CGI.query_string#"  name="test" method="post"> 
    <a href="##">#First_Name# #Last_Name#</a>
    <input type="submit" Name="Logout" value="Logout">
   </form>
  </cfoutput>
 </cfif>
```

I have try with `<cfajaximport>` , but fail to solve it.

The code below is autosuggest

```
<cfinput type="text"
         name="Name"
    maxlength="100"
    size="30"
    validateAt="onSubmit, onServer"
                                 autosuggest="cfc:Restaurants.LookupRestaurant({cfautosuggestvalue})">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the HTML form, which is going to break your Ajax call.  When the autosuggest ajax call runs, it will receive both the HTML form and the results which will no longer be in the format that the autosuggest widget expects.

Comment: mean change the form became cfform ?

Comment: No.  What i mean is, you are ALWAYS printing out the form.  ALL requests will have that code, which means when your Ajax request runs it returns the HTML form + whatever the result of the ajax was.  If the autosuggest widget expects JSON, for example, instead it will get the HTML form + JSON.  This is not valid JSON and will break.  You need to use firebug to look at the result of the Ajax call.  I suggested this on your other SO question.  I assume you are doing this in your Application.cfm file?  Application.cfm is NOT a good place for your output code.  This will be output for every request

Comment: You should post your autosuggest code as well.  It will help determine the problem.

Comment: I try to move the the code with the file same with auto suggest, it can be work.
I though put the main code in Application.cfm is better way. 
Thank for your advise !